# Multiple maven version from different sources

Tags: java, macos, maven, terminal, jdwp

I have 2 different versions of maven installed on my MacBook. One is through a company tooling.

```
% mvn -v
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Colorizing...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 08:22:22-0700)
Maven home: /Users/abc/.bootstrap/packages/maven3.1.1/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

One of my projects needs maven version >3.2.5 and I have a newer version through brew

```
% brew list maven
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/bin/mvn
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/bin/mvnDebug
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/bin/mvnyjp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/bin/ (4 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/boot/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/conf/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/lib/ (75 files)
```

If I try to use this directly, I get the following error:

```
% /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/bin/mvn -v
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

How do I fix it? How do I switch to the new version when building my old project? Maybe I can delete the 3.1.1 version? How would I do that? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Where is this: `Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice` comming from? Manually configuration?

Comment: Probably when I run maven commands, it's trying to load it in the background. This is what my $MAVEN_OPTS looks like ```% echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx4g -Xms2g -server -d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true```

Comment: Why is jdwp configuration set etc... remove all that stuff just try first without any configuration... and the agent? Why is it needed? really need 4 GiB for build? Which version of JDK do you use? -server option would only be neccesary if you are on a 32 bit OS? Remove that as well MaxPermSize etc. is not needed...

Answer (score 0):

The Maven you installed using Homebrew is using a newer version of Java than you expect.  This newer version does not support the JVM flags you pass in through the MAVEN_OPTS variable, and therefore refuses to start.

To fix it, unset MAVEN_OPTS (or set it to the empty value) and then run Maven.

That said, it looks like you have been provided with a set of options for setting up the JVM to have specific characteristics AND running Maven in debug mode so you can attach a debugger.   I would suggest forgetting the first kind until you  prove you have a need for them, and either use Maven in a debug configuration in your IDE or run the `mvnDebug` script (next to the `mvn` script) from the command line for launching Maven so you can attach a debugger.  Note that in my experience you only need this to troubleshoot an Maven error.